# Error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: json, csv, python-3.7

I'm trying to convert a JSON to CSV but now it is giving an error:

> 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes'

The error starts on the line:

```json
jsonDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
```

And I gave print (`jsonObj`).

Could someone help me I don't know what else to do.

Heading:

```py
    # versao python #3.7.3
    import json
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    
    def flatten_dict(d, acc={}):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
               flatten_dict(v, acc)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for l in v:
                    flatten_dict(l, acc)
            else:
                acc[k] = v
        return acc
    
    
    data = []
    with open('testejson.json') as f:
        for jsonObj in f:
            jsonDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
            data.append(jsonDict)
            
    df = json_normalize(data)
    df.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
```

The JSON file and very big plus this and its structure:

```json
    {
      "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
      "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
      "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
      "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "1052",
      "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2021-03-16T16:00Z",
      "CVE_Items" : [ {
        "cve" : {
          "data_type" : "CVE",
          "data_format" : "MITRE",
          "data_version" : "4.0",
          "CVE_data_meta" : {
            "ID" : "CVE-2002-0184",
            "ASSIGNER" : "cve@mitre.org"
          },
          "problemtype" : {
            "problemtype_data" : [ {
              "description" : [ {
                "lang" : "en",
                "value" : "NVD-CWE-Other"
              } ]
            } ]
          },
          "references" : {
            "reference_data" : [ {
              "url" : "http://distro.conectiva.com.br/atualizacoes/?id=a&anuncio=000475",
              "name" : "CLA-2002:475",
              "refsource" : "CONECTIVA",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=101974610509912&w=2",
              "name" : "20020425 [Global InterSec 2002041701] Sudo Password Prompt",
              "refsource" : "BUGTRAQ",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=101975443619600&w=2",
              "name" : "20020425 Sudo version 1.6.6 now available (fwd)",
              "refsource" : "BUGTRAQ",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=101979472822196&w=2",
              "name" : "20020425 [slackware-security] sudo upgrade fixes a potential vulnerability",
              "refsource" : "BUGTRAQ",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=102010164413135&w=2",
              "name" : "20020429 TSLSA-2002-0046 - sudo",
              "refsource" : "BUGTRAQ",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.debian.org/security/2002/dsa-128",
              "name" : "DSA-128",
              "refsource" : "DEBIAN",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.iss.net/security_center/static/8936.php",
              "name" : "sudo-password-expansion-overflow(8936)",
              "refsource" : "XF",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/820083",
              "name" : "VU#820083",
              "refsource" : "CERT-VN",
              "tags" : [ "US Government Resource" ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.linux-mandrake.com/en/security/2002/MDKSA-2002-028.php3",
              "name" : "MDKSA-2002:028",
              "refsource" : "MANDRAKE",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.linuxsecurity.com/advisories/other_advisory-2040.html",
              "name" : "ESA-20020429-010",
              "refsource" : "ENGARDE",
              "tags" : [ "Patch", "Vendor Advisory" ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.novell.com/linux/security/advisories/2002_014_sudo_txt.html",
              "name" : "SuSE-SA:2002:014",
              "refsource" : "SUSE",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.redhat.com/support/errata/RHSA-2002-071.html",
              "name" : "RHSA-2002:071",
              "refsource" : "REDHAT",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.redhat.com/support/errata/RHSA-2002-072.html",
              "name" : "RHSA-2002:072",
              "refsource" : "REDHAT",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/4593",
              "name" : "4593",
              "refsource" : "BID",
              "tags" : [ ]
            } ]
          },
          "description" : {
            "description_data" : [ {
              "lang" : "en",
              "value" : "Sudo before 1.6.6 contains an off-by-one error that can result in a heap-based buffer overflow that may allow local users to gain root privileges via special characters in the -p (prompt) argument, which are not properly expanded."
            } ]
          }
        },
        "configurations" : {
          "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
          "nodes" : [ {
            "operator" : "OR",
            "cpe_match" : [ {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.5.9:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p4:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.3p7:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.4:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.4p1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.4p2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.5p1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:todd_miller:sudo:1.6.5p2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            } ]
          } ]
        },
        "impact" : {
          "baseMetricV2" : {
            "cvssV2" : {
              "version" : "2.0",
              "vectorString" : "AV:L/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C",
              "accessVector" : "LOCAL",
              "accessComplexity" : "LOW",
              "authentication" : "NONE",
              "confidentialityImpact" : "COMPLETE",
              "integrityImpact" : "COMPLETE",
              "availabilityImpact" : "COMPLETE",
              "baseScore" : 7.2
            },
            "severity" : "HIGH",
            "exploitabilityScore" : 3.9,
            "impactScore" : 10.0,
            "obtainAllPrivilege" : true,
            "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
            "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
            "userInteractionRequired" : false
          }
        },
        "publishedDate" : "2002-05-16T04:00Z",
        "lastModifiedDate" : "2021-03-16T14:15Z"
      } ]
    }
```